# Find the window that lastlost focus

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, pinvoke, ui-automation

Is there any way to find which window on screen last lost focus? I am open to using any of the following:

1. pivoke/win apis
2. uiautomaion
3. any other technique

I tried with the `Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(OnFocusChangedHandler)`
but it only give the details about the new window which has gained the process.**I want to know is there any way to get which window has lost(not gained) the focus?**

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Edit1: I want to avoid polling.That would be the last resort.

Edit2: MSDN says that UI automation provides this

```
Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(focusHandler);

void OnFocusChange(object src, AutomationFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //MSDN Says that here we get the elements that have lost and received focus. 
    // I am getting the element which received focus by doing

      AutomationElement element = src as AutomationElement;
      //element.Current gives the element that received focus
      //i was not able to get anything which gives the element that lost focus 
}
```

Comment: As a hack, you could poll regularly the current focused window.

Comment: that would be the last resort...i want to avoid polling...gave updated the question